# How to Make Console Command Availbable to AWS Lambda Written in Java

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I would like to run a piece of Java code in AWS Lambda that calls a shell command (in my case `wkhtmltopdf`). I can't seem to figure out how to package the Lambda for this to work:

`Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf": error=2, No such file or directory: java.io.IOException`

I've been able to make it work with Node.js. I guess this is due to the "package" being extracted once uploaded whereas with Java the jar stays compressed and thus the executable isn't accessible from `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [AWS Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). Packagin `bin/wkhtmltopdf` into a zip file and creating a layer using something along the lines:

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name wkhtmltopdf \
--description "wkhtmltopdf executable" \
--zip-file fileb://$(pwd)/wkhtmltopdf.zip \
--compatible-runtimes java8
```

After that I was able to select and apply the layer (remember to press save).